# Django ORM non-strict search through multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

There is the Model with some fields. I need to search some rows in the table and check multiple fields: f1,f2,f3. 
So, query may be matched one to three fields. For example, f1 matches, but f2 and f2 not. Or f1 and f2 matches but f3 not. And so on.

I think it should be something like this:

```
models_list = Model.objects.filter(f1__contains=query, 
                                   f2__contains=query, 
                                   f3__contains__query)
```

But how to do this condition  optional and not mandatory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.filter(
    Q(f1__contains=query) |
    Q(f2__contains=query) |
    Q(f3__contains=query)
)
```

If you are using MySQL, consider using [`search`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#search) instead - it is a lot faster than `contains` because it uses full text indexing.