# Change Django autocomplete_fields label

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I'm trying to set a custom label for all of the items of a type in `autocomplete_fields`.

Until now, for a drop-down list, one would use

```py
...
class CustomDisplay(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "Some custom text: {}".format(obj.name)
...
somethings = CustomDisplay(queryset=Something.object.all())
...
```

but using this with `autocomplete_fields = (somethings,)` will result in autocomplete canceling and showing me a dropdown with the custom text.

Answer (score 12):

The reason the field shows a normal `select` widget is that, when you define your custom field, you don't set the widget as an `AutocompleteSelect`.

In the `ModelAdmin` class where you specify your `autocomplete_fields`, import your `CustomDisplay` and `AutocompleteSelect` and add the following method:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect


class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['something']

    ...

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        db = kwargs.get('using')

        if db_field.name == 'something':
            return CustomDisplay(queryset=Something.object.all(), widget=AutocompleteSelect(db_field.remote_field, self.admin_site, using=db))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

That will only display the custom text when you view an existing instance. When you view the autocomplete drop down, and select an entry, the label is not generated from `label_from_instance()`, but from a straightforward `str()` call inside `AutocompleteJsonView`.

So assuming you only want to change the label in the autocomplete widget (to change the label across the board you would obviously just change the model `__str()__` method), you also need to create a custom class in `admin.py` that modifies the `get()` method in `AutocompleteJsonView`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import AutocompleteJsonView
from django.http import Http404, JsonResponse


class CustomAutocompleteJsonView(AutocompleteJsonView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.model_admin.get_search_fields(request):
            raise Http404(
                '%s must have search_fields for the autocomplete_view.' %
                type(self.model_admin).__name__
            )
        if not self.has_perm(request):
            return JsonResponse({'error': '403 Forbidden'}, status=403)

        self.term = request.GET.get('term', '')
        self.paginator_class = self.model_admin.paginator
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()

        # Replace this with the code below.
        #
        # return JsonResponse({
        #     'results': [
        #         {'id': str(obj.pk), 'text': str(obj)}
        #         for obj in context['object_list']
        #     ],
        #     'pagination': {'more': context['page_obj'].has_next()},
        # })

        return JsonResponse({
            'results': [
                {'id': str(obj.pk), 'text': 'Some custom text: {}'.format(obj.name)}
                for obj in context['object_list']
            ],
            'pagination': {'more': context['page_obj'].has_next()},
    })
```

Now set the `autocomplete_view` on the `ModelAdmin` class that the autocomplete is displaying results for (not the `ModelAdmin` class where you specify autocomplete_fields):

```
def autocomplete_view(self, request):
    return CustomAutocompleteJsonView.as_view(model_admin=self)(request)
```

So if you have a `ModelAdmin` class called `YourModelAdmin` with `autocomplete_fields = ['something']`, you would set the `autocomplete_view` for the corresponding `ModelAdmin` class for your `Something` model.

Update for Django 4.2:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect
from django.contrib.admin.views.autocomplete import AutocompleteJsonView
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # This will change the view for all autocompletes.
    # You can handle specific cases within the autocomplete get() method.
    def autocomplete_view(self, request):
        return CustomAutocompleteJsonView.as_view(admin_site=self)(request)


admin_site = CustomAdminSite()


class CustomAutocompleteJsonView(AutocompleteJsonView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        (
            self.term,
            self.model_admin,
            self.source_field,
            to_field_name,
        ) = self.process_request(request)

        if not self.has_perm(request):
            raise PermissionDenied

        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if type(self.model_admin) == SomethingModelAdmin:
            return JsonResponse(
                {
                    "results": [
                        {'id': str(obj.pk), 'text': 'Some custom text: {}'.format(obj.name)}
                        for obj in context['object_list']
                    ],
                    "pagination": {"more": context["page_obj"].has_next()},
                }
            )
        else:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['something']

    ...

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        db = kwargs.get('using')

        if db_field.name == 'something':
            return CustomDisplay(queryset=Something.objects.all(),
                                           widget=AutocompleteSelect(db_field,
                                                                     self.admin_site,
                                                                     using=db))
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Wow!  I would have never figured this out

Comment: Unfortunately, Django 3.2 moved `autocomplete_view` off of `ModelAdmin`, and I haven't yet been able to figure out how to adapt the (great-looking!) solution above. I'll post here if I crack it but wanted to warn other readers that this solution may no longer work as expected.

Comment: @rossettistone Things have changed around a bit since my original answer. I've provided an update based on Django 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

On the parent admin use `autocomplete_fields`:

```
class ParentAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = (
       "sub_account_stuff",
       "other_sub_items",
    )
```

The `autocomplete_fields` use `search_fields` on the sub admin models, HOWEVER, you can override with `get_search_results` so I created a mixin like so, where parsing the request referer url can resolve the parent:

```
class AutoCompleteSearchParentIdsMixin:
    def get_parent_object_from_auto_complete_search(self, request):
        from urllib.parse import urlparse
        path_info = urlparse(request.headers.get('Referer')).path
        resolved = resolve(path_info)
        if resolved.kwargs:
            return MyParentModel.objects.get(pk=resolved.kwargs["object_id"])
        return None

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        parent = self.get_parent_object_from_auto_complete_search(request)
        if parent:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                parent_ids__contained_by=parent.ids
            )
            if search_term.isnumeric():
                queryset = queryset.filter(Q(id=int(search_term)) | Q(parent_id=int(search_term)))
            else:
                queryset = queryset.filter(Q(payload__Name__icontains=search_term))
        else:
            queryset = queryset.none()
        return queryset.distinct(), False
```

And mixed in to override `get_search_results` like so:

```
class SubAccountAdmin(AutoCompleteSearchParentIdsMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

class OtherSubItemsAdmin(AutoCompleteSearchParentIdsMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

And to change the way it is displayed, i added a custom `__str__` to the models.

```
class OtherSubItemsModel(models.Model):
   ...
   def __str__(self, obj):
      return f"<OtherSubItem id={self.id} name={self.payload.get('Name')}>"
```

Referenced:

- [Django ORM non-strict search through multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259855/django-orm-non-strict-search-through-multiple-fields)
- [Django: access the parent instance from the Inline model admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150088/django-access-the-parent-instance-from-the-inline-model-admin)
- [django admin - change search_fields results ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590760/django-admin-change-search-fields-results-ordering)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results