# Django Admin overwrite the __str__ method in an autocomplete_field

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to overwrite the `__str__` method in Django admin when using the `autocomplete_fields = ()` but the returned values are using `__str__`.

I have a form something like

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        
    placement = forms.Select(
        choices = Organisation.objects.active(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['placement'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{str(obj)} {obj.post_code}'
```

This will provide back a Select with the organisation name and post code in the dropdown fields.  But there are some 80k choices so I need to using autocomplete.  Within within `admin.py` I have

```
class LeadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LeadAdminForm
    autocomplete_fields = ('placement',)
```

As soon as I add the autocomplete_fields I lose my postcode and it reverts to just showing the `__str__`

Hoa can I used autocomplete_fields and overwrite the `__str__` method?

Comment: You cannot override the `__str__` method in your `Organisation` model ?

Comment: Can you share the `Lead` model? Is `Lead.placement` a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: This is the only place I want to override the `__str__` method which is why I cannot override within the model

Comment: `Lead.placement` is a foreign key

Comment: So maybe this answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56865950/8439435

Comment: Looks promising - I'll try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered through Benbb96 comment above which I've copied here so I can close it

> So maybe this answer can help you :
> stackoverflow.com/a/56865950/8439435 – Benbb96