# How to override the autocomplete view for a specific model field in the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

I need to override the way a Select2 widget of a particular `ForeignKey` is behaving in the Django (4.1) admin.

Namely, I am trying to increase the number of objects returned by the AJAX requests and defined by `paginate_by` in [`AutocompleteJsonView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/views/autocomplete.py).

Sadly [this great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56865950/3281427) no longer works with Django 4.

How can I extend `AutocompleteJsonView` and somehow tell Django to use my custom view?

EDIT: my current workaround is to override `get_paginator` on the `ModelAdmin` by setting `paginator.per_page` to whatever value is suitable, but that doesn't answer to broader question of customising the autocomplete behaviour of Select2 widgets in the Django admin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for this after upgrading from Django 2.2 to 3.2, since autocomplete_view moved from Admin to Site.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.autocomplete import AutocompleteJsonView

class MySite(AdminSite):
    def autocomplete_view(self, request):
        if request.GET['model_name'] == "mymodel":
            return CustomAutocompleteJsonView.as_view(admin_site=self)(request)
        else:
            return super().autocomplete_view(request)

class CustomAutocompleteJsonView(AutocompleteJsonView):
    pass
    # Override serialize_result, get, or get_paginator here
```

(That being said, it might be a better idea to implement and use a custom api instead of trying to re-use this undocumented class that could change again any time.)